# React-native Flatlist not refreshing data

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to add data dinamically to my flat list with the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text,FlatList,Button,Alert} from 'react-native';

export default class Lista extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {dados: [
      {key:"valeu 1"},
      {key:"value 2"}
    ],
    refresh : false
    };
  }

  adicionar(){
    this.state.dados.push({key:"value 3"})
    this.state.refresh = !this.state.refresh

  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
        data= {this.state.dados}
        extraData = {this.state.refresh}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
        />
        <Button title="Adicionar"
            onPress={this.adicionar.bind(this)}>      
        </Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I am able to push data to the "dados" object with `this.state.dados.push({key:"value 3"})` but when I switch the  `this.state.refresh` variable to true my Flatlist doesn't render the last value.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never mutate the state directly. Try to call `this.setState()` function in order to perform better app develompent. It could be the reason why Flatlist is not been re-rendered.

```
adicionar(){
    const { refresh, dados } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      dados: [...dados, {key:"value 3"}], //that is a better way to update Array-States
      refresh: !refresh
    })
}
```

Comment: It is working partially, it only shows "value 3" with your solution. Tried switching to const { dados, refresh} = this.state;  but the result was the same.

Comment: Nervermind I didnt thoguht those '...'  were actually part of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

To update a value in state you should always use ***setState*** method.

```
adicionar(){
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      dados: [...prevState.dados, {key:"value 3"}],
      refresh: !prevState.refresh
    })
    )
}
```

Comment: refresh it not declared in that scope

Comment: @HelmerBarcos refresh variable should be inside  state hence moved it in state

Answer (score 0):

please replace `extraData = {this.state.refresh}` to `extraData = {this.state}`